# Add a link to Netsuite transaction with custom body field

Tags: html, sql, tags, netsuite

We have a need for an additional ADVANCED PDF/HTML printing template in Netsuite. Also, we are currently unable to add an extra print action using scripting (I know this would be the simple solution, and hopefully in time we will be able to do this)

I want to know if it is possible by using a `CUSTOM BODY FIELD`, and using the formula/default values.

I currently have a custom field setup, using the following formula, however when I open the transaction I get a `ERROR: Invalid Expression`

> ```
> <a https://system.eu2.netsuite.com/app/accounting/print/hotprint.nl?regular=T&sethotprinter=T&template=131&id='||{salesorder.internalid}||'&label=Picking+Ticket&printtype=pickingticket&trantype=salesord>PRINT</a>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is invalid because it is missing the opening and closing quotation marks around the string literal.

I've also added the missing `href` attribute and HTML quote marks, and changed the URL to be relative so the link is valid across data centers and enviroments.

```
'<a href="/app/accounting/print/hotprint.nl?regular=T&sethotprinter=T&template=131&id=' || {id} || '&label=Picking+Ticket&printtype=pickingticket&trantype=salesord">PRINT</a>'
```

Comment: That helped the error: invalid, i can see the link now. But when I click on the link, it opens (to a new page) unexpected error. There must be missing a step somewhere

Comment: @SimonG See my edit, I think `{internalid}` should be changed to just `{id}`